# como hago para que me multiplique el valor en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como hago por que quiero que el resultado sea 4 y no sea 'aa' del siguiente codigo fuente

```
set1=input ('Entra letra para multiplicar su valor en numero x2: ')
a=2
b=3
c=4
d=5
e=6
muestra=2*set1
print (muestra)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas un diccionario  `letras = {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 4, "d": 5, "e": 6}`
 para almacenara las parejas en vez de usar variables? Si aún así quieres usar variables necesitas un condicional o usar las más crípticas `getattr`, `eval` o diccionario `globals`.... Un diccionario sería la opción lógica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que lees con `input` es una cadena. En tu caso, si el usuario responde `a`, el valor de `set1` es la cadena `"a"`, por lo que lógicamente al multiplicar por dos se utiliza el operador de multiplicación de cadenas cuya misión es repetir la cadena el número de veces indicado y así sale `"aa"`.

Lo que necesitas es convertir la cadena `"a"` en el valor `2` (y la cadena `"b"` en 3, etc.)

Aquí caben varias posibilidades:

### 1. ¿Son esos valores en concreto? (solución con `ord`)

Es decir, ¿quieres que siempre `"a"` sea 2, `"b"` sea 3, etc. o eso era sólamente un ejemplo?

Si son esos valores particulares los que quieres usar, ya que van creciendo de 2 a 6 por orden alfabético del nombre de la variable, puedes usar el código ascii de la letra del usuario como punto de partida para convertirlo en número:

```
muestra = (ord(set1)-ord("a")+2)*2
```

`ord()` te da el código de la letra. Al restarle el código de `"a"`, si la letra era `"a"` sale 0, si era `"b"` sale 1, etc. Basta sumar 2.

### 2. Si los valores pueden ser otros (solución con `dict`)

En ese caso puedes tener un diccionario como tabla de traducción de letra a número, como sugiere el comentario de FJSevilla:

```
traduccion = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
if set1 not in traduccion:
    print("La letra introducida no es válida")
else:
    muestra = 2 * traduccion[set1]
    print(muestra)
```

### 3. Si tienen que ser variables (solución con `eval`)

Es decir, si no vale la solución del diccionario. En este caso podrías intentar construir una expresión en forma de cadena de caracteres:

```
expresion = "2*{}".format(set1)
```

Si el usuario tecleó `"a"`, entonces `expresion` sería la cadena `"2*a"`. Seguidamente puedes usar `eval(expresion)` para que Python "ejecute" esa cadena como si fuera una expresión python dentro de un programa. De este modo trataría la `a` que aparece en la expresión como una variable, y calcularía correctamente el resultado buscado.

Sin embargo **no debes hacer esto**. `eval()` es peligroso y usarlo directamente para evaluar cadenas que hayan sido introducidas por el usuario te pone en riesgo. Imagina que el usuario, en lugar de teclear `"a"` teclea `"[1]*1000000"`, en ese caso la `expresion` valdría `"2*[1]*1000000"` y cuando python la evalúe creará una lista compuesta por dos millones de unos, lo que tardará un buen rato y consumirá mucha memoria. Naturalmente el usuario puede meter números aún mayores y causar que tu programa deje de responder, lo cual, si tu programa fuera parte de un servidor, sería un ataque de *denegación de servicio*.

### 4. Si tienen que ser variables (solución sin `eval`)

Python tiene la función `globals()` que te devuelve un diccionario cuyas claves son todas las variables globales, y cuyos valores son los que tengan esas variables. Análogamente tiene también `locals()` para las variables locales de la función que se esté ejecutando.

Por tanto esta solución equivale a la 2, sólo que no tienes que crear tú el diccionario si no que ya está creado con las variables de tu programa. Usando este enfoque:

```
traduccion = globals()
if set1 not in traduccion:
   print("La letra introducida no es válida")
else:
   muestra = 2*traduccion[set1]
   print(muestra)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como dice FJSevilla la solución de los diccionarios es adecuada a tu programa

```
set1=input('Entra letra para multiplicar su valor en numero x2: ')
valor = dict()
valor['a']=2
valor['b']=3
valor['c']=4
valor['d']=5
valor['e']=6
muestra=2*valor.get(set1)
print (muestra)
```

Es importante que comprendas realmente que esta pasando, sin embargo ten en cuenta que la solución 1 de abulafia es muy pythonica pero debes comprender que esta pasando.