# como establecer valores en varias variables en un bucle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yo tengo 3 variables:

```
var1 = 4 
var2 = 5 
var3 = 6
```

Y mediante un `for` quisiera ir seteando sus valores, de modo que se mantenga `var` pero de alguna forma, el index vaya cambiando (ese 1,2,3), para poder cambiar valores de todas las variables a por ejemplo:

```
var1 = 10 
var2 = 10 
var3 = 10
```

Lo que quiero aprender es porque si tengo muchas variables cambiarlas mediante un bucle. espero haberme explicado. muchas gracias desde ya.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.so]. Paara estos casos no uses variables, usa un diccionario por ejemplo `{"var1": 4, "var2": 5, etc}`. Es posible hacer lo que quieres pero no es lo más recomendable, no es legible ni buena práctica en general.  Mirate https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/182452/15089

Comment: O podrías usar listas, de este modo `var` sería el nombre de la lista y luego mediante subíndices puedes acceder a `var[0]`, `var[1]`, `var[2]`, etc. El índice puede ser otra variable sobre la que puedes iterar en un bucle. Por ejemplo `var= [4,5,6]; for i in range(3): var[i]=10`

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer, tal como lo quieres hacer, en Python, no es posible. Pero hay alternativas, que son esas que otros ya te están dando. Dejo el comentario solo para que sepas que no es posible.

Comment: @ArianJM Hombre, por poder sí que se puede. Todo es posible en un lenguaje dinámico e interpretado como python (pista: `eval()`). Pero no es la forma correcta de abordar este problema.

Comment: @abulafia Hmmmm..., interesante. Acabo de hacerlo con `exec()`, con `eval()` no he podido. Pero tienes razón. Posible, lo es.

Answer (score 3):

Utilice listas a menos que desee algunas características muy específicas que se encuentran en las bibliotecas de la matriz.
Python realmente tiene tres estructuras de datos primitivas:

```
tuple = ('a','b','c')
list = ['a','b','c']
dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

En este caso solo me enfocaré en las listas con los siguientes ejemplos básicos.

```
list.append('d') #Con esto podemos agregar otro valor, llámese('d') a la lista
list[0] #Esto nos sirve para obtener el primer elemento de ('a')

list.insert(i, x) #  Inserta un elemento en una posición dada. El primer argumento es el índice del elemento antes del cual se inserta, por lo que a.insert(0, x) se inserta al principio de la lista, y a.insert (len (a), x) es equivalente a a.append (X). 

list.pop(2) #Eliminará los elementos por posición (índice), eliminará el tercer elemento.
list.remove(x) #Quita el primer elemento de la lista cuyo valor es x.

list.index(x) # Devuelve el índice en la lista del primer elemento cuyo valor es x. Es un error si no hay tal artículo.

list.count(x) # Devuelve el número de veces que x aparece en la lista.

list.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) # Ordene los elementos de la lista en su lugar (los argumentos se pueden usar para ordenar la personalización, consulte ordenados () para su explicación).

list.reverse() # nvertir los elementos de la lista, en su lugar.
```

Para este caso en específico te recomiendo utilizar listas, puedes visitar esta página para revisar su documentación y tener mayor información: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Espero haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

```
var1=10
var2=10
var3=10
var4=10
var5=10
var6=10
var7=10
var8=10
var9=10
var10=10
```

escrito en forma corta:

```
for i in range(1,10+1):
    exec("var" + str(i) + "=10")
```

Comment: Deberías explicar mejor tu respuesta. Por ejemplo, explicar `exec`.

Comment: El comando 

for i in range(1,10+1):
    exec("var" + str(i) + "=10")

sirve para ejecutar los comandos
var1=10
var2=10
var3=10
var4=10
var5=10
var6=10
var7=10
var8=10
var9=10
var10=10

en un sólo bucle, si reemplazamos exec por print, quedaría
var1=10
var2=10 y así sucesivamente. Exec recibe string o texto y ejecuta lo que recibe

Comment: Edita tu respuesta para incluir esa información. Thx